# Local proxy application as "window" for a SaaS one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webview, electron

I'm trying to find a way to have a locally running very lightweight application (just Javascript, HTML and CSS) or proxying that application from the web through a local "window-to-the-web-application"-application that handles the client's local stored data.

Using things like ElectronJS would be overkill compared to how much I wont need from it.
I would just need a webview (native OS one)/local browser that renders the HTML, executes the Javascript code and some kind of API to the OS filesystem to create/read the sqlite database and interact with it.

My thinking:

1. Developing the app with a framework like quasar that has nice Vue.js components.
2. Use Webpack to minify it the most as possible. (Just one MyApp.html file wouldn't be possible I guess)
3. By clicking on this html file, the default browser on the clients machine gets opened.
4. What's missing and problematic this way are OS filesystem access and SQLite handling.

Sketch for more clarification:
[image]

Is that doable?

Comment: Just to let you know, I found your question interesting, and I started working on a Proof of Concept last night. I might be able to have something working tonight after work, I'll keep you updated. One thing is for sure, as you noted, a simple HTML file won't be enough in order to access the filesystem. I'm trying it with Neutralino, which seems to have the smallest footprint

Comment: Update: I tried to create a cool dev environment where you can use Vue-cli-service as a devserver, alongside Neutralino's server to access OS functionality during development. But I discovered some problems with Neutralino. They made a couple of mistakes (i.e. making their POST API calls `www-form-url-encoded`, but sending the data as JSON and not accepting an `=` sign, which any standard library will add in url-encoded forms ‍♂️). This makes setting up any kind of proxy during development a real pain, since proxies will add the `=`... It's doable, but I've spent too much time on this, sorry

Comment: Thanks @blex. That's more I could ask for. I researched a bit about the storage side, and SQLite seems a bit problematic. Found about Lovefield that also could fit.

Comment: To make sure I wasn't disambiguate about the word "proxy". I didn't mean the one from computer networking, but more of a placeholder kind of layer between OS and application from the web that can be mounted/bootstrapped locally to have the best of both worlds combined for that use case.

Comment: Yes, I got that :) Characters in comments are limited, so I wasn't clear myself. Here is [why I was talking about a proxy](https://pastebin.com/raw/haZtc1HM)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, @blex. Today I found out about Tauri which is similar to Neutralino but seem to offer a lot more. FYI: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri#comparison-between-tauri-and-electron